# Quick Reference Guide for Site Settings?

Tags: configuration, 2007

Is there a "quick reference" guide or "cheat sheet" type document for each of the available options within the "Site Settings" page in Sharepoint 2007 ?

The settings page that I'm talking about is shown in this image:

[image]

and is the one accessed via the "Site Actions" drop-down on the right-hand side of the screen as shown below:

These are all of the "Site Settings" grouped into categories such as "Users And Permissions", "Look and Feel", "Galleries" & "Site Administration".

What I'm ideally looking for is a sort of "cheat sheet" that lists each of these options, perhaps as bullet-points, and provides a quick small paragraph of text that describes each option.

For example, I'd like to see something like the sample below, but for each of the options available within the "Site Settings" configuration page:

> **Look And Feel**
>
> - Title, description, and icon
>     *This option allows you to enter a textual name for the site along with a
>     description and icon.  The title and
>     icon are displayed in the "header"
>     area on the top of each page within
>     the site and the description is
>     displayedon the main area of the
>     site's default or home page.*

Comment: A quick Google hasn't turned up much - perhaps a few of us with some free time rattle something up?

Answer (score 1):

I've not run across anything, but I've got to say that this is a great idea!  Perhaps you could refer to some admin books and build your own cheat sheet using the format you started here.  A couple of my favorite SharePoint 2007 admin books are "**SharePoint 2007: The Definitive Guide**" and "**Inside SharePoint 2007 Administration**".